# 90/180 Schengen Visa traveling within Europe

Tags: schengen, 90-180-visa-rules, ryanair

This Friday, my girlfriend is coming to Denmark via Oslo on a flight originating in New York (EWR). I'm not sure on how it actually works in terms of her getting a visa. We have plans to travel to Brussels for a weekend while she is here, flying Ryanair, but they require a special visa check for non-EU travelers:

> You must go to the visa check/bag drop desk and have this document stamped before proceeding through security.

Is she issued the visa as a stamp in her passport when she goes through passport control in Oslo, or would this happen in Denmark (or some other way)?

What exactly does Ryanair expect, to prove you have a visa?

Comment: Which 'the visa' are you concerned about? If your friend is a US citizen, she will not need a visa for a short-term visit to the Schengen area and she will also not get one. If she is from a country, which citizens require a visa to visit the Schengen area, she will have to apply for a visa at a consulate before going there.

Comment: I'm simply worried that she won't be able to get on the plane with Ryanair without a stamp, to prove that she has a visa or is allowed to be in a Schengen country.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming she is American, she will get only a Schengen Entry Stamp in Oslo on her passport, assuming she has all other standard requirements fullfilled. Flight to Denmark is considered domestic, only a boarding pass is mostly required, although a random check might again happen to her (or to anybody) asking for ID.

For Brussels, again its domestic, make sure you print her boarding pass, because Ryan Air will stamp that pass after they see her passport & entry stamp.

Ryan Air will check nationality from the passport, and know that few nationalities dont need visa sticker in passport, and even in any case, even if a person has visa sticker in passport, Ryan Air can never stamp it or any other page is passport. They always stamp Visa Checked or Visa Ok on boarding pass at check in desk.